# What is the best way to access CloudKit from C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, cloudkit, cloudkit-js

I have a website using ASP.NET (Blazor server-side) on which I'd like to display data loaded from CloudKit. What is the best way for me to use only C# code to query CloudKit and receive data and pass the data to a Blazor component that is already open in `Host.cshtml`? If that's not possible, then what would be the best way for me to implement a similar functionality using JavaScript and passing the data to a Blazor component that is already open in `Host.cshtml`. I currently cannot display any code because I have no clue whatsoever on how I can accomplish this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does "already open in `Host.cshtml`" mean?  Is this a Blazor App or not?

Comment: This is a Blazor app. I'm not sure how to explain it as I am a beginner in ASP.NET. I was referring to the fact that Blazor components are usually called in the `Host.cshtml`. I just felt like that was necessary to add. Sorry for the confusion because as I said, I am a beginner in ASP.NET.

Comment: OK. With serverside Blazor you can just use HttpClient.  I  am not familiar with CloudKit, look for libraries or base it on the CloudKit documentation.